# Implementing css does not display

Tags: html, css

I encountered a very strange thing, my css did not respond properly, my button should have a blue background color and white text but it did not display properly
Does anyone know how to solve it?
I try move the code over div container, it still does not working well.
I have no idea to solve this problem.
html code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Restaurant Club</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">
</head>

<body>
        <section>
            <h2>Welcome to restaurant Club</h2>
        </section>

    <div class="div_design">
        <aside>
            <form>
                <fieldset class="label_design">
                    <legend class="title_design">Evaluate your choice of restaurant</legend>
                    <label for="Users" class="label_design">Restaurant evaluate</label>
                    <input id="Users" type="text" class="text_input" placeholder="Restaurant evaluation">
                    <button type="button" class="button_design" value="add">Add</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </aside>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css code

```
body {
  padding: 1.2em;
  font: 1.3em "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #F3F2EF;
}

a {
  color: #00B7FF;
}

.div_design {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height:auto;
  margin: 8%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  border-radius: 1%;
};

.field_design {
  border:none;
};

.label_design {
  display:block;
  margin: 0.25em;
};

.title_design {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin: 2%;
  border-bottom: 1% solid blue;
}
.text_input {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: block;
  margin: 0.25em;
  border-radius: 3px;
};

.button_design {
  color:blue;
  margin: 0.25em;
  background-color: rgba(51,121,245,0.88);
};
```

it is really strange, i never met this problem.
[image]

Comment: Right click on the button, "inspect element", and take a look at the CSS rules that've been applied.

Comment: The main problem is that some css is implemented, but there are still some parts of css that don't work, I don't know why

Comment: (In your case, it's the semicolon on the `.text_input` class. Shouldn't be there.) Remove all the semicolons after your `{}`s.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I am not mind this problem before

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to remove those semicolons in your css file.

I tried, it works for me.

Can you try to remove them ?

Comment: Yes it words. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. This happens because you added semicolons (;) at the end of the class or element. You have to remove all these semicolons.

[image: Refer below image]

Answer (score 0):

so this is what you need to do, remove the semi colons  after the "}"

the "color" attribute is for the font color not the background so that needs to change, just use the color names instead of rgba to see what works, change the css code for the button with the lines below, the margin is fine.

color: white;

background-color: blue;